# htaccess routing with one domain and couple folders

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I have 2 project - 2 different folders but one domain.

Stucture:

```
--root
  --main
    --angular5 project with own .htaccess
  --blog
    --simple html page
```

I need, when user go to any link, redirect him to folder `main` with angular project. If user go to link /blog, redirect him to blog folder.

Angular proect .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

My try of root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog/$ blog/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/index.html?path=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^/blog [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  /blog/$1  [L]
```